# ColdFusion Forms

Tags: mysql, forms, coldfusion

I'm trying to make a form that accesses a MySQL database. But all of this is new to me. I think I might be trying to reach too far beyond my basic understanding of this. Here is my question.

I have a form. In this form I have the connection made to the database and am able to post to the database. What I'm trying to do is have an option field with "tile 1", "tile 2", "tile 3". For each "tile" I'd like to have the rest of the fields saved under that tile ID. I'd also like to be able to pull that tiles information when selecting the tile from the option field.

Here is my current code. Please keep in mind I'm new to all of this. Thanks.

**Form:**

```
<cfform method="post" name="TileAdAdmin" action="index.cfm">
          <cfoutput>
              <table width="500px">
              <tr>
                <td height="159"><label class="labelStyle">Tile Ads</label></td>
                <td>
                  Tile Number:<select name="TAID" id="TAID">
                    <option value="0">None</option>
                    <option value="1">Tile 1</option>
                    <option value="2">Tile 2</option>
                    <option value="3">Tile 3</option>
                  </select><br /><br />
                  Headline:
                   <input name="TAHL" type="text" id="TAHL" title="TAHL" value="#variables.ta.TAHL#" maxlength="30" />
                   <br />
                   Image Name: 
                   <input name="TAImage" type="text" id="TAImage" title="TAImage" value="#variables.ta.TAImage#" maxlength="30" />
                   <br />
                   Discription:                   
                   <textarea name="TADiscription" cols="30" rows="6" id="TADiscription" title="VimeoID">#variables.ta.TADiscription#</textarea>                   <br />
                  </td>
              </tr>
            </table><br />

            <input type="hidden" value="#variables.controller#" name="controller">
            <input type="hidden" value="#variables.action#" name="action">
            <input type="Submit" value="Submit" name="Submit" class="formInput">
          </cfoutput>
        </cfform>
```

**DAO Code:**

```
    <cfcomponent name="TADAO" displayname="" hint="" output="false">

  <cffunction name="read" access="public" returntype="Void" output="false" hint="CRUD method">
    <cfargument name="ta" type="ta" required="yes" />

    <cfset var qRead = 0 />
    <cfquery name="qRead" datasource="#Application.dbsource#" >
      SELECT
        TAID,
        TAHL,
        TAIMAGE,
        TADISCRIPTION
      FROM
        T026_TILE_ADS
    </cfquery>

    <cfif qRead.RecordCount>
      <cfset arguments.ta.setTAID(qread.TAID) />
      <cfset arguments.ta.setTAHL(qread.TAHL) />
      <cfset arguments.ta.setTAImage(qread.TAIMAGE) />
      <cfset arguments.ta.setTADiscription(qread.TADISCRIPTION) />
      <cfelse>
      <cfthrow type="emptyRecordset" errorcode="TADAO.read.emptyRecordset" message="Unable to locate the TILE_AD data record." />
    </cfif>
  </cffunction>

  <cffunction name="update" access="public" returntype="Void" output="false" hint="CRUD method">
    <cfargument name="TA" type="TA" required="yes" />

    <cfquery name="qUpdate" datasource="#Application.dbsource#">
      UPDATE
        T026_TILE_ADS
      SET
        TAID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric" value="#arguments.ta.getTAID()#" />,
        TAHL = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#arguments.ta.getTAHL()#" />,
        TAIMAGE = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#arguments.ta.getTAImage()#" />,
        TADISCRIPTION = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_text" value="#arguments.ta.getTADiscription()#" />
     </cfquery>

  </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

**Component code:**

```
<cfcomponent displayname="ta" hint="" output="false">

<cfproperty name="TAID" displayname="" type="numeric" />
<cfproperty name="TAHL" displayname="" type="string" />
<cfproperty name="TAImage" displayname="" type="string" />
<cfproperty name="TADiscription" displayname="" type="string" />


<cffunction name="init" access="public" returnType="TA" output="false" hint="">
  <cfset this.TAID = 0 />
  <cfset this.TAHL = "headline" />
  <cfset this.TAImage = "IMAGE" />
  <cfset this.TADiscription = "Discription" />

  <cfreturn this />
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="getTAID" access="public" output="false" returntype="numeric">
    <cfreturn this.TAID />
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="setTAID" access="public" output="false" returntype="void">
    <cfargument name="TAID" type="numeric" required="true" />
    <cfset this.TAID = arguments.TAID />
    <cfreturn />
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="getTAHL" access="public" output="false" returntype="string">
    <cfreturn this.TAHL />
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="setTAHL" access="public" output="false" returntype="void">
    <cfargument name="TAHL" type="string" required="true" />
    <cfset this.TAHL = arguments.TAHL />
    <cfreturn />
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="getTAImage" access="public" output="false" returntype="string">
    <cfreturn this.TAImage />
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="setTAImage" access="public" output="false" returntype="void">
    <cfargument name="TAImage" type="string" required="true" />
    <cfset this.TAImage = arguments.TAImage />
    <cfreturn />
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="getTADiscription" access="public" output="false" returntype="string">
    <cfreturn this.TADiscription />
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="setTADiscription" access="public" output="false" returntype="void">
    <cfargument name="TADiscription" type="string" required="true" />
    <cfset this.TADiscription = arguments.TADiscription />
    <cfreturn />
</cffunction>

 <cffunction name="dump" access="public" output="true" returntype="void">
  <cfoutput>
    Tile:         #this.TAID# <br />
    Headline:         #this.TAHL# <br />
    Image:         #this.TAImage# <br />
    Description:         #this.TADiscription# <br />
    </cfoutput>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: Niloct, absolutely not true. Adobe just released ColdFusion 10, Railo and Blue Dragon are still releasing new versions of their CFML open source alternative. Not even sure what you mean by 'verbose'. Please educate yourself.

Comment: Nate: Not sure what you're asking here. Please can you explain in clear terms what you're trying to do.

Comment: You took the comment the wrong way buddy. I started with CF when it was on Allaire more than a decade ago (the 'old' argument), and moved on since then. Although I personally believe that today there are better alternatives than its markup verbosity in coding (the 'other' argument), I do not intend to offend at all.

Comment: im using CF because that is what i have to work with. I have no control on that right now. so if i can get some help on this it would be great... thanks

Comment: ok im have a form. the form needs to save data to a MYSQL DB and i have a pull down selector with options Tile1. Tile2. and Tile3. when someone enters info and selects tile1 id like for it to pull the info from the DB from the last entry and allow us to change it and update it and then save the new info back to the DB. and since there are three tiles it needs to be able to enter info for each and pull info for each. i hope that helps

Comment: Is there any way you can remove this wall of code and only put in the salient bits for what you're having trouble with? Help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TAID as a primary key**

`TAID` is the identifier of each of your tiles, so first of all you need to add it to a `WHERE` clause in the `SQL` statements.

---

```
  UPDATE
    T026_TILE_ADS
  SET
    TAHL = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#arguments.ta.getTAHL()#" />,
    TAIMAGE = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#arguments.ta.getTAImage()#" />,
    TADISCRIPTION = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_text" value="#arguments.ta.getTADiscription()#" />
  WHERE
    TAID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric" value="#arguments.ta.getTAID()#" />
```

---

```
  SELECT
    TAID,
    TAHL,
    TAIMAGE,
    TADISCRIPTION
  FROM
    T026_TILE_ADS
  WHERE
    TAID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric" value="#arguments.ta.getTAID()#" />
```

---

<strike>**Calling the update query before the select query**</strike>

Update: after analysing your database code, the order of definition of cfquerys is not important since they are inside `CFFUNCTIONS` of the `CFCOMPONENT`.

---

**Selecting OPTION with Jquery**

Finally you will need to select the tile from the submitted form, you can spice your code with [Jquery](http://jquery.com) (add inside, at the end of the `CFOUTPUT`)

---

```
<!--- (beginning of CFOUTPUT ...) --->
<input type="Submit" value="Submit" name="Submit" class="formInput">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('SELECT##TAID').val(#variables.ta.TAID#);
});
</script>
</cfoutput>
```

---

### Edit 26/07

**Using `<CFSELECT>` instead**

In the `CFOUTPUT` the `TAID` field is a simple HTML `SELECT`. Since we want to pull records from the DB, try this:

Put before the `CFOUTPUT` tag:

```
<cfquery name="qryTiles" datasource="#Application.dbsource#">
  SELECT
    TAID,
    TAHL,
    TAIMAGE,
    TADISCRIPTION
  FROM
    T026_TILE_ADS
</cfquery>
```

And replace:

```
<select name="TAID" id="TAID">
<option value="0">None</option>
<option value="1">Tile 1</option>
<option value="2">Tile 2</option>
<option value="3">Tile 3</option>
</select>
```

with:

```
<cfselect name="TAID"
 size=1
 multiple="no"
 query="qryTiles"
 value="TAID"
 display="TAID"
 queryPosition="below">
  <option value="0">None</option>
</cfselect>
```

Comment: i believe ive made the changes and its still not not pulling or adding rows of info to the DB. but i might have missed something ill double check again but i do have the TAID set as PrimaryKey. what settings do i need to set for each of the fields?

Comment: Hi Nate, back to work. Those will not `INSERT` new records to the DB indeed, since we are just calling `UPDATE` records. You would have to add a cfquery and check if there is no record in the DB with the tile id = TAID, then issue an insert. Not a big issue if you've done everything you pasted above.

Comment: For a start, you can insert by hand a couple of TAID both in the DB and in the  `<select name="TAID" id="TAID">`, and test the script.

Comment: i have 3 TAIDs created in the DB. right now im getting an error from the cfthrow saying unable to locate the TILE_ADS data record.

Comment: Today this topic latest edit here showed that you used `CFFUNCTION` wrapping the `qRead` and `qUpdate` cfqueries. This will break my second suggestion above (relocation of cfquery). Are each of they still inside their `CFFUNCTION` ?

Comment: yes this is correct they are wrapped in two separate CFFUNCTION tags

Comment: ok with playing around with the code some more i have been able to get the code to update the records in the DB and update them for each of the TAIDs. so that works... thanks... but id like to have it pull up the old info from the DB before the person updates it... its not pulling it in. then when i try to set it up to take that info that they have entered and post it on the webpage all i get is "cfTA2ecfc1257799038$funcGETTAID@1fd3665" and there is one for each field. i really appreciate all this help. Thanks

Comment: Do you have a published version of this ? You can e-mail the address of that to me (see my profile) and the actual source code, so we can finish this task =)

Comment: sorry Niloct but i dont see your email on your profile. can you email me?